# Android <include> didn't work with ViewBinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I have an issue with this "new" Android View Binding. I get an exception when I try to use a   `<include>`
in my XML-Layout file:
 `<include layout="@layout/teaser_agreement" />`

The include file is just a basic layout file. Everything works fine if I replace the `<include>` tag directly with the layout code which should be included.

This is the exception from the generated class:

```
error: incompatible types: TeaserAgreementBinding cannot be converted to ViewDataBinding
        setContainedBinding(this.mboundView11);
```

Any suggestions?

Thx,
Mirco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will also have to wrap your `teaser_agreement.xml` with layout tag. So it would be like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<--!Rest of your xml code-->
......
..........
............

</layout>
```